# str_split adding empty elements in array end when reading from file

Tags: php, arrays, string, split

I found interesting problem while I was trying to achieve something simple like splitting string into array. The only difference here is that Im trying to take the string from .txt file
My code is the following:

```
$handle = fopen("input.txt", "r"); // open txt file
$iter = fgets($handle); 

// here on first line I have the number of the strings which I will take. This will be the for loop limitation
for ($m = 0; $m < $iter; $m++) 
{    
    $string = fgets($handle); // now getting the string
    $splited = str_split($string); //turn it into array, this is where problem appears
    print_r ($splited); // just show the array elements
    echo "<br>";
    echo count($splited);
    echo "<br>";
 }
```

This is the content of my .txt file

```
4
abc
abcba
abcd
cba
```

I tried with array_filter() and all other possible solutions/functions. Array filter and array diff are not removing the empty elements, no idea why... Also in my txt file there are no blank spaces or anything like that. Is this a bug in a str_split function ? Any logic behind this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra whitespace is a newline. Each row except the last technically contains all of the text contents you see, plus a newline.

You can easily get rid of it by e.g.

```
$string = rtrim(fgets($handle));
```

Also, `fgets($fp);` makes no sense since there's no variable `$fp`, should be `fgets($handle);` given your above code.

Comment: Thats it... Simple one, didnt knew that lastline is included. I changed the variable names while posting but obviously missed one, my original code is okay but thanks for noticing this.

Answer (score 1):

Trimming the spaces and need to change your `fgets($fp)` to `fgets($handle)` as there's no variable like of `$fp`.You need to update your code into as

```
for ($m=0;$m<$iter;$m++) 
 {
$string = trim(fgets($handle)); //
$splited = str_split($string); //turn it into array, this is where problem appears
 print_r ($splited); // just show the array elements
  echo "<br>";
 echo count($splited);
   echo "<br>";
 }
```